# A search Idea for multi linked record as tree

Tags: algorithm, solr, architecture

I Have multi-records connected to multi-records are connected to other records.

The result I need when I search using any record key to get the result with all connected records and other connected records.

I have accomplished this to assign a master key for all related records, but the issue is that when there are many relations it will take time to update all records, and also when I remove a connection between tow records also I have to update one of the sides with another master key.

I don't know if I explain it well, but here is an image may give you a clearer view :

[image: DATA RELATION]

if I search for node No# 1 I should get all result in the query,

If I break the connection between #3 and #4 and search for #3 the result should be only 1,2,3,4

Hope, I was clear

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you seen https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/graph-traversal.html ?